# How to check if a character is a non-word boundary

Tags: java, regex

In Java regular expression, it has "\B" as a non-word boundary.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

If I have a 'char', how can I check it is a non-word boundary?

Thank you.

Comment: The "boundary" in question is an anchor: a position between (or before/after) characters, and not a character in itself (similar to how `^` doesn't refer to a character, it refers to the position before the first character).  So the question itself is a bit meaningless, you might need to clarify so we know exactly what you want.

Answer (score 7):

The boundary has a special meaning. It has actually a zero-length match and can therefore not be matched on a single character. It is used to determine the position between a non-word char and a word-char. Also see http://regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html.

I however understood that this question is more whether the given char can possibly denote the start or end of a word boundary. From the javadoc which you linked ([here](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is the latest version):

> **Predefined character classes**
>
> `.`   Any character (may or may not match line terminators)
> `\d`  A digit: `[0-9]`
> `\D`  A non-digit: `[^0-9]`
> `\s`  A whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`
> `\S`  A non-whitespace character: `[^\s]`
> `\w`  A word character: `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`
> `\W`  A non-word character: `[^\w]`

So, a word character matches `\w`. A non-word character matches `\W`. So:

```
String string = String.valueOf(yourChar);
boolean nonWordCharacter = string.matches("\\W");
```

Comment: Note: this doesn't tell you if it's a boundary, just that it's a non-word char. The concept of a boundary is relevant to an ordered collection and can not be reasonably applied to a single char.

Comment: Further clarification, boundary is a context specific term, and examining only a char removes the context used for the `"\B"` regex.

Comment: Indeed, the boundary has a special meaning. It has actually a zero-length match. Also see http://regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html This is actually used to determine the position between a non-word char and a word-char. I however understood that his question was more whether the given char can possibly denote the start or end of a word boundary.

Comment: I'd add that last comment to your original question to emphasize the fact that `\b` and `\B` don't match a character but a position, since that is what michael is confused about.

Answer (score 2):

The question is very peculiar, but it's true that a `\w` on its own is surrounded by `\b`. Similarly, a `\W` on its own is surrounded by `\B`. So for the purpose of word boundary definitions, `^` and `$` are non-word characters.

```
    System.out.println("a".matches("^\\b\\w\\b$")); // true
    System.out.println("a".matches("^\\b\\w\\B$")); // false
    System.out.println("a".matches("^\\B\\w\\b$")); // false
    System.out.println("a".matches("^\\B\\w\\B$")); // false

    System.out.println("@".matches("^\\b\\W\\b$")); // false
    System.out.println("@".matches("^\\b\\W\\B$")); // false
    System.out.println("@".matches("^\\B\\W\\b$")); // false
    System.out.println("@".matches("^\\B\\W\\B$")); // true

    System.out.println("".matches("$$$$\\B\\B\\B\\B^^^")); // true
```

The last line may be surprising, but such is the nature of anchors.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: What you say is not true: all that stuff is really broken in Java. If you compile up a pattern like `\b\w+\b` and use the Matcher#find method against the string `élève`, you will not find **any matches whatsoever**.  Java regexes are super-extremely broken. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261) for why, *and* what you can do about it.

Comment: Fantastic explanation thanks - that really makes it much clearer how this works.

Answer (score 1):

```
((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
```

or if you want to digits to be also parts of a word:

```
((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
```

Answer (score 1):

A boundary is a position *between* two characters, so a character can never be a boundary.

If you want to match a character that is not surrounded by word boundaries, e. g. the character `b` in `abc`, then you can use

```
\B.\B
```

Remember to escape the backslashes in a Java string, as in

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\B.\\B");
```

Comment: In practice, it's fine to define boundaries as something that exists only between two characters. However, it's actually more liberal than that, at least in Java. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173) for a discussion of just what exactly a `\b` boundary is and how to wrestle your regex into behaving more the way you may want it to.